# How to use a Spring Service in Drools rules?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, drools, kie, mvel

I'm working with drools engine in the construction of an alert system. we need to execute a method of a **@Service instantiated** by Spring Framework on the actions of the rule (RHS), when the conditions are met.

What would be the way to get the **@service instance** created by Spring Framework to be used by the action (RHS) of the Drools rule?

I have followed the following indications:

1. Using the form *import function* (**Rule1.drl**). This solution does not work because the class is instantiated in drools and requires static methods to be executed.
2. Using a *global Session* variable (**Rule2.drl**). This solution throws me an exception at "runtime" indicating that it is not the same class type.

Any ideas on how to use it?

As

File: **Rule1.drl**

```
package com.mycompany.alerts.Alert;

import function com.mycompany.alerts.service.SecurityService.notifyAlert;

rule "Activate Alert Type"
salience 9000
when
  $alert: Alert(type == "TYPE1") 
then
  System.out.println("Running action:" + drools.getRule().getName());
  $alert.setActive(Boolean.TRUE);
  notifyAlert($alert.getStatus(),$alert.getSmsNumber());    
  System.out.println("End action:" + drools.getRule().getName());
end
```

File: **Rule2.drl**

```
package com.mycompany.alerts.Alert;

global com.mycompany.alerts.service.SecurityService securityService;

rule "Activate Alert Type 2"
salience 9000
when
  $alert: Alert(type == "TYPE2") 
then
  System.out.println("Running action:" + drools.getRule().getName());
  $alert.setActive(Boolean.TRUE);
  securityService.notifyAlert($alert.getStatus(),$alert.getSmsNumber());    
  System.out.println("End action:" + drools.getRule().getName());
end
```

File: **SecurityService.java**

```
package com.mycompany.alerts.service;

import com.mycompany.alerts.service.UserRepository;

@Service
@Transactional
public class SecurityService {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityService.class);

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public SecurityService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public void notifyAlert(String status, String sms) {
         System.out.println("Alert notify with:" + status + " sms:" + sms);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use the setGlobal function of kieRuntime as:

```
kieRuntime.setGlobal("securityService", securityService);
```

then you can declare/use this variable in your drl file as :

```
global SecurityService securityService.
```

PS:- KieRuntime object can be obtained as: KieRuntime kieRuntime = (KieRuntime) kieSssion;

Comment: or you can just do kieSssion.setGlobal("securityService", securityService);