# Using drools rule of one entity to invoke methods related to second entity

Tags: spring-boot, drools, kie

Using the rules for one entity, is it possible in drools to invoke the methods related to a second entity?

Using Spring boot, I have the following Task entity.

```
@Entity
public class Task extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

    private String title;
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "assignee_group_id")
    private UserGroup assigneeGroup;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TaskType type;

    //getters and setters
}
```

And the UserGroup entity

```
@Entity
public class UserGroup extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Task.class, mappedBy = "assigneeGroup", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Task> tasks;

    //getters and setters
}
```

The TaskType enum is defined as

```
public enum TaskType {

    STORE("Store"), ACCOUNTS("Accounts");

    private String formattedName;

    TaskType(String formattedName) {
        this.formattedName = formattedName;
    }

    public String getFormattedName() {
        return formattedName;
    }
```

}

I also have two UserGroups `Store` and `Accounts` in the database. Now what I want to do is when a user creates a `Task` of type `Accounts`, I would like to set the assignee group as the `Accounts` group, and similarly for the `Task` of type `Store`.

I have defined the rules as

```
rule "Task for Store"
    when 
        taskObject: Task(type.formattedName=="Store")
    then
        System.out.println("task for store invoked");
    end

rule "Task for Accounts"
    when 
        taskObject: Task(type.formattedName=="Accounts")
    then
        System.out.println("task for accounts invoked");
    end
```

This works perfectly fine. But now, I want to do something like

```
rule "Task for Store"
    when 
        taskObject: Task(type.formattedName=="Store")
    then
        //find user group with name Store
        //set this user group as the assignee group
    end

rule "Task for Accounts"
    when 
        taskObject: Task(type.formattedName=="Accounts")
    then
        //find user group with name Accounts
        //set this user group as the assignee group
    end
```

So far I've only found examples that either print out message in drools rule file like I've done above or invoke setters for fields of primitive data type. How can I (or is it even possible) to invoke setters for fields referring to a different entity? Please let me know if this is not even considered as best practice. I am just starting on drools so I don't have much idea here.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem after some research. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43346204/how-to-use-a-spring-service-in-drools-rules) was really helpful. I defined a `findByNameOrCreate` method in `UserGroupService` that accepts the userGroup name and returns a userGroup instance. Then where I defined the `kieSession`, I set a global to `UserGroupService` like the following:

```
public Task save(Task task) {
    KieSession kieSession = kieContainer.newKieSession("rulesSession");
    KieRuntime kieRuntime = (KieRuntime) kieSession;
    kieRuntime.setGlobal("userGroupService", userGroupService);
    kieSession.insert(task);
    kieSession.fireAllRules();
    kieSession.dispose();
    return taskRepository.save(task);
}
```

Then I defined the rules as

```
package rules

import com.packagename.domain.Task
import com.packagename.service.UserGroupService

global UserGroupService userGroupService;

rule "Task for Store"
    when
        taskObject: Task(type.formattedName=="Store");
    then
        taskObject.setAssigneeGroup(userGroupService.findByNameOrCreate("Store"));
    end

rule "Task for Accounts"
    when
        taskObject: Task(type.formattedName=="Accounts");
    then
        taskObject.setAssigneeGroup(userGroupService.findByNameOrCreate("Accounts"));
    end
```

Now whenever the `save` method is invoked, using the name, the task is assigned to the correct userGroup.