# how can I use spring boot Service class in .drl files in Optaplanner Planning projects?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, optaplanner

not in **drools project**, just in **Optaplanner planning project**.
Optaplanner with drools engine!!!
[use spring boot service classs in drools project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43346204/how-to-use-a-spring-service-in-drools-rules)

**here more info about this question**
[code structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82F70.png)

**here service's function in drl file**

```
rule "RuleLimosis"
when
    ViewPatient($RevId:Id,$PatientID:PatientID, PatientID != null)
then
    boolean limosisFlag = viewPatientService.getChecklistLimosis($RevId);
    System.out.println("empty stomach status: " + limosisFlag);
```

end

runtime info use @ProblemFactProperty in planning solution class

1 System.out.println("in java file viewPatientService is: " + viewPatientService);

2 System.out.println("in drl one file viewPatientService is: " + viewPatientService);

code 1 have correct value
code 2 null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap the service in a class and create a @ProblemFactProperty field of that wrapper class in the planning solution.

But your constraints shouldn't be calling remote services as that will cripple your score calculation speed.

Comment: I edited my question, my code structure and part of my drl file were posted. this question disturbed me all day. lol